# Stereo analyzer(visualizer) as a VST plugin

Tags: vst, stereo, cubase

I recently saw [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvSooaUgVQw) about stereo field. The author is using Stereo Analyzer feature of the `Inspector XL` software to visualize the resulting stereo effect, this is what it looks like:

[image]

Unfortunately, this software has been discontinued, and was never available in 32 bit version, which makes it impossible for me to use it. Are there any other tools, preferably in a form of a VST plugin, that can visualize stereo field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is often called a [Goniometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goniometer_%28audio%29) or Correlation meter. There are plenty of VST plugins that will display a goniometer view for stereo correlation analysis. Just use your favorite search engine, now that you know the proper terms.

[This](http://www.fluxhome.com/products/freewares/stereotool) looks like what you are looking for. I don't have any experience with it myself, however.